# Start Running an Excel Macro in another workbook while closing original workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Spreadsheets, for testing called Red and Blue.
I need to run a macro in Red, which opens Blue, Closes Red, Does some stuff in Blue, then Reopens red and does some stuff in Red. I can get The macro in Red to Open blue and run a macro in Blue, but if that macro in Blue closes Red, it stops and won't reopen Red.

This is the Macro in Red:

```
Sub Macro1()

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Carey.Zimmer\Documents\Practice\September 2022\BookHopping\Blue.xlsm"
Range("B2") = "Macro 1 Run Successfully in Blue"
Workbooks("Red.xlsm").Activate
Range("B2") = "Macro 1 Run Successfully in Red"
Application.Run ("'Blue.xlsm'!Macro2")

End Sub
```

And this is the Macro in Blue:

```
Sub Macro2()

Workbooks("Red.xlsm").Activate
Range("B3") = "Macro 2 Step 1 Run Successfully in Red"
Workbooks("Blue.xlsm").Activate
Workbooks("Red.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("Blue.xlsm").Activate
Range("B3") = "Macro 2 Run Successfully in Blue"
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Carey.Zimmer\Documents\Practice\September 2022\BookHopping\Red.xlsm")
Range("B4") = "Macro 2 Step 2 Run Successfully in Red"

End Sub
```

I start with both workbooks empty and only Red open when I run Macro1.

I end with Only Blue Open, with Macro1 run successfully in both, and only step 1 of Macro2 run successfully in Red.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Are you sure _red_xlms_ was closed, while _Macro1_ is still running?

Comment: No Error message, but the series of events I see are:
1) I run Macro1
2) Blue Opens
3) I get prints in Both Blue and Red
4) I get a print in Red from Macro2
5) Red closes

Once the red workbook closes, nothing else happens. My understanding is that because Macro2 was called by Macro1 which was called From Red, Macro2 is actually running in Red, even though it is stored in Blue.